# PHP write JSON file via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I want to post some data via jQuery/Ajax into a JSON-File, but I don't receive the data as an JSON Object.

My JSON content looks like this:

> foo=abc&bar=def

but I want this one:

> {
>       "foo" : "abc",
>       "bar" : "def
>     }

**HTML**

```
<form id="foobar">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="foo" name="foo" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
        var request;

        $("#foobar").submit(function(event){

        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        var $form = $(this);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        request = $.post("dataSaveAjax.php", {json : JSON.stringify(serializedData)});

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$file = fopen("dataAjax.json","w+");

$json = $_POST['json'];

$jsonDecode = json_decode($json);

fwrite($file, $jsonDecode);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: Do not use `$form.serialize();` make your json and then to `ajax` call. Make json `{ "foo" : "abc", "bar" : "def }` and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `serialize` then use

```
var data= JSON.parse($("#foobar").serializeArray()); //not serialize()
```

> If an object/array gets passed  [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), it's
>   serialized via [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).
>
> If a string get passed [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it doesn't do anything
>   further.

Your code should be

```
    var request;

    $("#foobar").submit(function(event){

    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    var data= {
         "foo":$("#foo").val(),
         "bar":$("#bar").val()
     };
    //don't do this if you want in json formate
    //var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    request = $.post("dataSaveAjax.php", {json : JSON.stringify(data)});

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or You can use

```
var serializedData = $form.serializeArray();
```

Comment: Why should the OP's code be this?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

Your data should already be formatted as JSON due to the `JSON.stringify` call in your JS. The json_decode in your PHP file is undoing the work of `JSON.stringify` -- just write the value of `$_POST['json']` to the file and you should be good.

```
<?php

file_put_contents('dataAjax.json', $_POST['json']);
```

Should be all you need to do on the PHP side.

Comment: "Your data should already be formatted as JSON due to the JSON.stringify call in your JS" — It is, but the data serialised as a JSON text is a URL Form Encoded JavaScript String and not a JavaScript Object.

Comment: You are correct, I missed that. The second part still stands though :)